# How to check if `MultiSelectField` is empty or not in Django?

Tags: django

In my model I have a field `department` which is a `MultiSelectField` and I give the `blank=True` to that field for some reasons. Now I want to check if user fills the field or not. I have tried to get data from `request.POST` and gave it a condition using `len()` function like this `if len(field) == 0:` but I got an error. Everything works just fine until I added `teacher_year = request.POST['teacher_year']`

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    teacher_department = MultiSelectField(choices=department_choice, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class TeacherRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['teacher_year', ...]
```

views.py

```
def teacherRegisterView(request):
    form = TeacherRegisterForm()
    template_name = "attendance/login-register/teacher_register.html"
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TeacherRegisterForm(request.POST)
        teacher_year = request.POST['teacher_year']

        if len(teacher_year) == 0:
            messages.warning(request, "Just a remind! You didn't select deparment!")
            return redirect('teacher_register')
        elif form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your account was created! You can log in now.")
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

the error I got

```
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'teacher_year'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiValueDict` is inherited from normal `dict`. So you can use [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict.get) method with it:

```
teacher_year = request.POST.get('teacher_year') # if request.POST doesn't contain teacher_year it returns None
if teacher_year:  
    ...
```